# SQL How to join two tables and extract result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Here is my Airport Table:

```
id code airport 
1  MAA  Chennai Airport
2  DEL  Delhi Airport
```

Here is my Equipment Table:

```
id type Desc
1  Q400 Q Series
2  B737 B Series
```

And Here is my Schedule Table:

```
id station equipment
1  1       2
2  2       1
```

Here is my expected result:

```
id station equipment
1  MAA     B737
2  DEL     Q400
```

How can I do this ?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select schedule.id, schedule.station, flight_schedules.equipment
inner join airport where schedule.station = airport.code
```

How can I get the expected result.

Comment: looking at it now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN according to your requirements as indicated on the diagram below. On the other hand, you can follow this approach in order to join multiple tables:

```
SELECT * FROM    
A INNER JOIN
  B INNER JOIN
    C INNER JOIN
      D INNER JOIN
        E INNER JOIN F
        ON F.eid = E.id
      ON E.did = D.id
    ON D.cid = C.id
  ON C.bid = B.id
ON B.aid = A.id
```

Here is the diagram for understanding JOIN types in MSSQL below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT s.id, a.code AS station, e.type AS equipment FROM Schedule s
LEFT JOIN Airport a ON a.id = s.station
LEFT JOIN Equipment e ON e.id = s.equipment
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know which language do you use but i brought this example which uses `sql` language and may be it works for some other languages or all of them:-

```
SELECT Schedule.id, Airport.code, Equipment.type
FROM ((Schedule
INNER JOIN Airport ON Schedule.station = Airport.id)
INNER JOIN Shippers ON Schedule.equipment = Equipment.id);
```

Comment: Hey here is my fiddle.. Can you update on it.. am not getting answer exactly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac051a/1

Answer (score 0):

*Hallo there,
here is the right answer, what you want to have.
But your expacted result is wrong, because you put equipmnet id 2 in table schedule. That why the answer look different by me *

**The right code**

```
SELECT Sch.[equipment]
      ,Air.code
      ,Equ.type
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Scheule] as Sch
  INNER JOIN [Test].[dbo].[Airport] as Air
  ON Air.id = Sch.station 
  INNER JOIN [Test].[dbo].[Equipment] as Equ
  ON Equ.id = Sch.id
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58UvK.png)